# Getting "Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input" when using ffmpeg to convert tga to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, image-conversion, tga

I've used ffmpeg to convert a bunch of tga files into an mp4 just fine for a few weeks, but it broke for no apparent reason earlier today. I have a pastebin with `-loglevel debug` [here](https://pastebin.com/mrFm9kqb), but the command I use is the same as the one that has worked before -- `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i triangle%03d.tga output.mp4`, and now it's broken.

The tga files are manually created by a C program that I wrote, but I don't think it's a problem with the file header/format because it hasn't been a problem with ffmpeg before before and I can open the tga files fine with `eog` and a tga viewer on Windows. Just in case it matters, here's the start of a hexdump for one of the files:

```
0000000 0000 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0780 0438
0000010 2018 ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb
0000020 eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce
0000030 ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87
0000040 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb
0000050 eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce
0000060 ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87
0000070 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb
0000080 eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce
0000090 ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87 87ce ceeb eb87
```

Would appreciate any help on fixing the ffmpeg (or alternative ways to convert tga to mp4).

Comment: I get this error in case of an incompatible audio file I want to add to my videos.